# Can you import financial data into Sage accounts?

Tags: export, financial-accounts

I am aware that you can export financial data from CiviCRM as an IIF or CSV file.  Can this data be imported into Sage accounts software?

Does anyone have any experience of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can import data directly to sage but using custom format

I did take a copy of CSV.php file and created a custom_export.php and then did the changes

But you can also directly change CSV.php file and do the required changes - In most case sage file will need only minimum fields like which can do by altering the SQL

**Type -  Account Ref - Nominal - Reference - Date - Transaction - Net - Vat - Tax code**

If you need more details please let me know - I guess this helps!!!

Comment: Reason why we use scripts to change CSVs outside of CiviCRM is b/c we trust CiviCRM will always be capable of outputting CSV files; overrides are time consuming re upgrades/testing.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh.  That's helpful. Could you provide the full path to the file you edited?  And, if you are happy to share it, it would be great to see your custom_export.php file.

Comment: CRM/Financial/BAO/ExportFormat/  you will find CSV.php and IIF.php - so you can do the changes in CSV.php file

Comment: look for function generateExportQuery() has the full SQL and makeCSV($export) is used for exporting

Comment: please drop a mail to ramesh@millertech.co.uk I am happy to discuss more and also to share the code - thanks

Comment: Can this make it in to some documentation or blog or somewhere?

Comment: Sure I will do  - I will try to release an extension if possible

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you'd export from CiviCRM into CSV and then wrap your data in `<tags>` like e.g. `<SalInvoice>` and `</SalInvoice>`. Also needs to add a line of vendor info, see:

https://partners.sagenorthamerica.com/irj/go/km/docs/sageKM/Simply%20Accounting%20by%20Sage/Assets/dev-import.pdf

Once you get one working by manually inserting tags and vendor info to CSV data
from your CiviCRM then you can script it.

Comment: Thanks Karin.  Do you have any experience of doing this yourself?

Comment: Not for Sage specifically - no. But other than QuickBooks - using some CSV format - yes.